# What is difference between trauern um and über?

Tags: preposition, expression, verb-usage

I really did not understand why the verb "trauern" has two prepositions,which are "um" and "über", could you please me clarify?

> Wir trauern um die Opfer der Gewalttat in München, die so plötzlich und grausam aus dem Leben gerissen worden sind. Ihren Angehörigen wünschen wir viel Kraft in diesen dunklen Stunden.

Comment: "über jmd./etw. trauern" sounds odd, do you have an example?

Comment: @Raketenolli yes, of course here http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=trauern&iservice=is its different usage

Answer (score 7):

I understand the [DWDS link](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=trauern) guidot quoted differently.

*trauern um* is in my understanding used when you directly refer to an object, not the cirumstances

> Sie trauert um ihren Vater
>   Sie trauert um ihren Ehering
>   Sie trauert um ihren Hamster

Personally I've never used nor heard *trauern über*, but from DWDS I understand that this can be used when you want to express that you're sad about something that *happened* to someone/something:

> Sie trauert über *den Verlust* ihres Vaters
>   Sie trauert über *das Verschwinden* ihres Eherings
>   Sie trauert über *den Tod* ihres Hamsters

If you said

> Sie trauert um den Tod ihres Hamsters

you'd mean that she mourns something which happened *to the death* of her hamster.

As I said above I've neither heard nor used *trauern über* before. Instead I'd have said

> Sie betrauert den Tod ihres Hamsters

Comment: Downvoter? Care to comment?

Answer (score 2):

According to [DWDS, see box with DWB headline](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=trauern) and to my personal instinct, one uses

1. *trauern um* if a person (or even a pet) has died, so typically its name follows in the sentence.
2. *trauern über* for all sorts of mishappenings, like the loss of a (precious) ring, long separation from a loved one etc.

Comment: Not really - I understand it as *über* is used if you refer to the *cause* of something happening to someone/something. In the DWDS example the person is sad about the *loss* of the silk scarf, not the silk scarf itself. If she mourned the silk scarf itself it would be *Sie trauert um ihren Sidenschal*.

Answer (score 2):

"trauern" is [normally only used with "um"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trauern). You would say "Ich trauere um meinen Freund." but not "Ich trauere über meinen Freund". You also wouldn’t say "Ich trauere über das verlorene Foto.".

However the noun "Trauer" can be used with "über" if the following object is not the thing that is mourned for but the thing that caused the mourning. E.g. "Die Trauer über den Tod des Großvaters war groß." Here "über" must be used because it’s the happening that caused the mourning. E.g. "Die Trauer über den Großvater war groß." wouldn’t work because it’s not the happening but the person that died itself.

(It’s of course comprehensible if you use "über" in both cases but it doesn't sound very elegantly.)